# Linux command that spawns multiple processes

Tags: command-line, process

I am looking for a linux command (like `ls`, `time` or anything similar) that spawns multiple processes. Anything which is to be run from a command line and not a shell script.

The reason is I want to see parent-child relationship on the `htop` and with different Process IDs.

Thanks

Comment: It might be easier to write a program than to use an existing command.  After all, commands exist to do something, and you might not want that something to be done.  You could easily write a program that spawns processes that do something like compute the first N primes, taking up processor cycles but having no other effect on your system.

Comment: Would `dig` do?

Comment: @jamesqf Thanks! I actually wanted to avoid writing a Multithread code myself. But, your argument on "commands do something which I don't want" gives me enough motivation to write one.

Answer (score 14):

The `&` command separator will do this for you.  Use it carefully and wisely, but here is a simple way to see process relationships:

```
$ sleep 5 & pstree -p $$
[1] 13369
bash(13337)─┬─pstree(13370)
            └─sleep(13369)
```

The `[1] 13369` shows that `sleep` (which has PID 13369), has been put into the background as Job #1.  `$$` returns to the shell the PID of itself, so we feed that into `pstree` to show the process tree with a root of our shell's PID, to show all child processes.

Comment: In fact, I want to avoid shell in the picture altogether. But, the hack is nice!

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to have any shells in the mix, you can simply use one of the "wrapper" programs that spawn another program to do something with it:

- `/bin/time sleep 60`
- `watch sleep 1` (this one will keep respawning `sleep`)